# Вывод email в html без преобразования

Tags: html, joomla

Как мне вывести email в html коде без преобразования? По умолчанию email выводится в тексте ссылкой. Мне нужно чтобы он выводился так же, как и весь остальной текст, т.е параграфом.

*Добавлено: HTML код формируется силами Joomla через добавление материала.*

Comment: @AIR - что там выкладывать? email@mail.ru отображается в параграфе ссылкой, при нажатии на которую открывается почтовый клиент, когда никаких mailto я не указывал, а просто разметил ее между тегами <p></p>

Comment: @FlapJack, чем вы редактируете HTML-страницу? Обозреватель (browser) отсебятины никогда не добавляет.

Comment: @ArhadВ Joomla через добавление материала